# Diff in `-Bsymbolic` behavior between gcc and clang?

Tags: c, gcc, linker, clang

Could it be that clang and gcc somehow implement `-Bsymbolic` differently?

```c
\\ exe.c
void f();

typedef void (*fptr)();
void compareFuncPtrs(fptr);

int main()
{
    compareFuncPtrs(f);
    return 0;
}
```

```c
\\ shlib.c
#include <stdio.h>

void f() {}

typedef void (*fptr)();
void compareFuncPtrs(fptr pExe)
{
    fptr pShlib = f;
    printf(pExe == pShlib ? "Equal\n" : "Different\n");
}
```

```
# buildAndRun.sh
echo
echo 'clang + Bsymbolic'
echo '-----------------'

clang -shared -Wl,-Bsymbolic -fPIC -o libshlib.so shlib.c
clang -L. -Wl,-rpath,. -o exe exe.c -lshlib 
./exe


echo
echo 'gcc + Bsymbolic'
echo '---------------'

gcc -shared -Wl,-Bsymbolic -fPIC -o libshlib.so shlib.c
gcc -L. -Wl,-rpath,. -o exe exe.c -lshlib
./exe
```

On my system `$ buildAndRun.sh` gives:

```
clang + Bsymbolic
-----------------
Equal

gcc + Bsymbolic
---------------
Different
```

The test system has gcc 10.3.1 and clang 16.0.2.
Can anyone reproduce this diff? What is the reason for it?

---

Edit: by @yugr's suggestion I diffed command lines and discovered that for some reason my clang adds `-pie` to the build of the executable. Indeed, when adding it manually to the gcc build I get the behavior I expected:

```
# buildAndRun.sh
...

gcc -fpie -L. -Wl,-rpath,. -o exe exe.c -lshlib
./exe
```

gives -

```
clang + Bsymbolic
-----------------
Equal

gcc + Bsymbolic
---------------
Equal
```

Any insight on how `-fpie` intervenes in `Bsymbolic`s impact?

Comment: `-Wl` flags are passed straight to the linker so I suggest to see if linker invocations are similar (you can emit them with `-v` flag). The issue does not repro on Ubuntu 22.04 (clang 14, gcc 11.4).

Comment: I can't explain the difference, but the C language spec says that two pointers to the same function compare equal (C17 6.5.9/6), so I'm inclined to think that GCC is buggy here.  I speculate GCC itself, not the linker, for I put the primary responsibility on GCC to provide conformance with the spec, regardless of foreseeable combinations of link options that do not inherently conflict with conformance.

Comment: The answer probably lies somewhere here, but is still beyond me: https://maskray.me/blog/2021-05-16-elf-interposition-and-bsymbolic